# Store background-color when hover a table row in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, background-color

I have an **ASP.NET GridView**. Each row has a different color depending on the value of one of the displayed fields. There are two possible values therefore there can be two different colors.

Now I want to **highlights the rows** on the GridView hovered by the mouse. The below script works perfecty but once I hover the mouse out the color becomes white for any row.

I would like to know if there is a way to somehow store the "original" color of the row when the mouse hovers in and put it back once the mouse hovers out.

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#<%=gdUpdateProduct.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hover(function() {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "Lightgrey");
                }, function() {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                });

            });
```

I tried this solution that seems quite logical to me but it does not work because the script does not store the value of color once it finishes to execute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#<%=gdUpdateProduct.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hover(function() {
                    var color = $(this).css("background-color");
                    $(this).css("background-color", "Lightgrey");
                }, function() {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                });
            });
```

Anybody might provide a solution? Thanks

Comment: BTW The problem with your solution is that the `color` variable only exists *within* the function where it is defined (`hoverIn`). It will never be accessible from the `hoverOut` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the previous (original) value in the **[`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** property:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=gdUpdateProduct.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.data('originalBg')) { // First time, no original value is set.
            $this.data('originalBg', $this.css('background-color')); // Store original value.
        }
        $this.css("background-color", "Lightgrey");
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.css("background-color", $this.data('originalBg'));
    });
});
```

If you're using **HTML5**, you can set the `data` property directly in the `<tr>` element ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)):

```
<tr style="background-color: #abc123;" data-originalBg="#abc123"> ... </tr>
```

That way, you can simply get away with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=gdUpdateProduct.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hover(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "Lightgrey");
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", $this.data('originalBg')); // Already set via the data-originalBg attribute of the `tr`
    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing it works like a charm! May you explain to me what originalbg is? Is it a property or just a variable?

Comment: The HTML5 example is really nice way to do this, and I would suggest this. For broswers that do not currently support HTML5, you can include the html5shiv script http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: @CiccioMiami `originalBg` just serves as the key I use to save the original background-color (`$this.data('originalBg', $this.css('background-color'))` saves the CSS value of `background-color` under the key `originalBg`). I use this to retrieve the original value (`$this.css("background-color", $this.data('originalBg'));` sets the CSS value of `background-color` to the originally stored value). (Does this even make sense?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
var color = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=gdUpdateProduct.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hover(
        function() {
            color = $(this).css("background-color");
            $(this).css("background-color", "Lightgrey");
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", color);
        });
    });
});
```

This way the varaible is global so will remember the value.

Answer (score 1):

If your highlight colour is static (which it appears to be) then an alternative approach would be to create a class called something like :

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #efefef !important;
}
```

and then simply:

```
$("#<%=gdUpdateProduct.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

And you'll get the original background colour back for free (tested in chrome 24.0.1312.57 m and FF 18.0.2 on win 7).

Toby